# Profiling Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, profiling, java-bytecode-asm

UPDATE:

I had mailed Shevek, founder of Karmasphere, for help. He had given a presentation on hadoop profiling at ApacheCon 2011. He advised to look for Throwable. Catch block for Throwable shows :

```
localhost: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class com.kannan.mentor.sourcewalker.ClassInfoGatherer has interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
localhost:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
localhost:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
```

Hadoop has ASM3.2 jar and I am using 5.0. In 5.0, ClassVisitor is a Super Class and in 3.2 it is an Interface. I am planning to change my profiler to 3.2. Is there any other better way to fix this issue?

> BTW, Shevek is super cool. A Founder and CEO, responding to some
>   anonymous guys emails. Imagine that.

END UPDATE

I am trying to profile Hadoop (JobTracker, Name Node, Data Node etc). Created a profiler using ASM5. Tested it on Spring and everything works fine.

Then tested the profiler on Hadoop in pseudo-distributed mode.

```
@Override
public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className,
        Class<?> classBeingRedefined, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain,
        byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {
     try {
        /*1*/ System.out.println(" inside transformer " + className);   
         ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(classfileBuffer);
           ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS);
         /* c-start */  //  CheckClassAdapter cxa = new CheckClassAdapter(cw);
             ClassVisitor cv = new ClassInfoGatherer(cw);
          /* c-end */    cr.accept(cv, ClassReader.EXPAND_FRAMES);
            byte[] b = cw.toByteArray(); 
            /*2*/System.out.println(" inside transformer - returning" + b.length);  
            return b;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println( " class might not be found " + e.getMessage()) ;
            try {
                throw new ClassNotFoundException(className, e);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    return null;
}
```

I can see the first sysout statement printed but not the second one. There is no error either. If I comment out from /* c-start */ to /* c-stop*/ and replace cw with classFileBuffer, I can see the second sysout statement. The moment I uncomment line

```
ClassVisitor cv = new ClassInfoGatherer(cw);
```

ClassInfoGatherer constructor:

```
public ClassInfoGatherer(ClassVisitor cv) {
super(ASM5, cv);
```

}

I am not seeing the second sysout statement.

What am i doing wrong here. Is Hadoop swallowing my sysouts. Tried sys err too. Even if that is the case why can i see the first sysout statement?

Any suggestion would be helpful. I think I am missing something simple and obvious here...but can't figure it out.

following lines were added to hadoop-env.sh

export HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS="-javaagent:path to jar $HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS"

export HADOOP_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS="-path to jar $HADOOP_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS"

export HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS="-javaagent:path to jar $HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS"

export HADOOP_BALANCER_OPTS="-javaagent:path to jar $HADOOP_BALANCER_OPTS"

export HADOOP_JOBTRACKER_OPTS="-javaagent:path to jar $HADOOP_JOBTRACKER_OPTS"

Comment: I tried using sjf4j logger. Didn't work. Created a logging rest service and used httpclient within transformer to do a post to this new service. It works for profiling other tools but not Hadoop.

Comment: I had mailed Shevek, founder of Karmasphere, for help. I had given a presentation on hadoop profiling at ApacheCon 2011. He adviced to lookout for Throwable. Catch block for Throwable shows :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hadoop had asm 3.2 and I was using ASM 5. In ASM5, ClassVisitor is a Superclass and in 3.2 it is an interface. For some reason, the error was a Throwable (credits to Shevek) and catch block was only catching exceptions. The throwable error wasn't captured in any of hadoop logs. So, it was very tough to debug.

Used jar jar links to fix asm version issues and everything works fine now.

If you are using Hadoop and something is not working and no logs to show any error's, then please try to catch Throwable.

Arun